# Why is there an error saying Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#1' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, html, domexception

When I click the "Open Account" button on the navigation I get the error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#' is not a valid selector.

```
// Page Navigation
document.querySelector('.nav__links').addEventListener('click', function (e){
  // Matching element
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.classList.contains('nav__link')) {
        const id = e.target.getAttribute('href');
        document.querySelector(id).scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
  }
});


document.querySelector(id).scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
```

...and here is the button HTML:

```
<li class="nav__item">
  <a class="nav__link nav__link--btn btn--show-modal" href="#">Open account</a>
</li>
```

Not sure what I'm missing to get rid of the error.

Comment: The button has `href="#"`. It's missing the ID after `#`, so what should it scroll to when you click on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event listener requires the `href` in the navigation link to be a valid selector for the element to scroll to. So change

```
<a class="nav__link nav__link--btn btn--show-modal" href="#">Open account</a>
```

to

```
<a class="nav__link nav__link--btn btn--show-modal" href="#someid">Open account</a>
```

and replace `someid` with the ID of the element that contains the account opening form that you want to scroll to.

Answer (score 0):

well e.target.getAttribute('href') returns "#"; you can't define an id with # sign it is not valid .
what i would suggets you
that code would be something like that

```
<li class="nav__item">
  <a  class="nav__link nav__link--btn btn--show-modal" href="#">Open account</a>
</li>
Not sure what I'm missing to get rid of the error.

Cheers
```

```
// Page Navigation
document.querySelector('.nav__links').addEventListener('click', function (e){
  // Matching element
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.classList.contains('nav__link')) {
       
        document.querySelector("a").scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
  }
});


document.querySelector("a").scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
```

Comment: Hard-coding a specific ID won't work for a navigation link.

Comment: oh did'nt know that i changed it

Answer (score 0):

You have to change **#** from href in `<a>` tag by any text. # itself is an id selector.

Answer (score 0):

because of how query selector is made you can't use it just like this.

[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) you have the documentation of querySelector() but a simple answear to you would be

```js
        const id = e.target.getAttribute('href');
        document.querySelector(`a href=${id}`).scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
```

Comment: That's not a valid selector.

Comment: I think you mean `a[href="${id}"]`. But you have to remove the `#` from the beginning of the `href` to get the ID.